# Which Framework is best to publish message in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, publishing, faye

I am trying to build an application where I would be publishing the message of user to all the other users who are subscibed to that tag?
I wanted to know which framework is good to go for development. I have heard about Faye and Redis but I have no idea which is best to use.

Answer (score 0):

In short

Redis is appropriate for inter-process messaging within your server cluster.

Faye is more appropriate if you want to provide a publicly accessible pub/sub service over the web.

Now you can choose what best suits you !!!